# Any use in returning values from generators now that async/await exist?

Tags: python, generator

[PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) introduced the ability to return values from generators, where `return expr` (almost the same as `raise StopIteration(expr)`) allows the calling side to retrieve the returned value in a manner different from yielded values, but only if code is explicitly written for that purpose. As rationale, the PEP explicitly mentions using `yield from` and `return` to implement coroutines.

Now that async/await have been part of the language for some time, is there still any practical use to returning (not yielding) values from generators?